# Closed file name of the page you will get data from

Tags: excel, vba

In a closed Excel file, I get data from the "account transactions" sheet, but the sheet names can be variable. How can we ensure that it always operates on the first first page of the closed file.

Thanks in advance.

```
Set cn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
Set Rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
cnstr = "Sağlayıcı=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Veri Kaynağı=" & ExcelDosyaYolu & ExcelDosyaAdi & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO"""
cn.aç (cnstr)
S1 = "[Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO;Database=" & ExcelDosyaYolu & ExcelDosyaAdi & "].[hesaphareketleri$A6:F ]"
Sorgu = "" & S1 & " F1,F2,F3,F4'ü seçin, burada F3 boş değil ve F3 'T%' gibi değil ve F3 'Tutar' gibi değil"
Set Rs = cn.Execute(Sorgu)`
```

I added `[" & Sheets(1).Name & "$]` instead of `[account transactions$A6:F]` but it didn't work

Comment: `Sheets(1).Name` refers to the current workbook, not to the workbook you're querying.  See the linked duplicate post for how to query the sheet names from a workbook.